# Nginx works on my linux machine but is not accessible from other computers in my local network

Tags: iptables, nginx, redhat-enterprise-linux, scientific-linux

In my LAN network I have a server with Scientific Linux (RedHat or Fedora based distro), I've done `yum install nginx` but the welcome page is not accessible from other computers in my network.

When I do `telnet open localhost 80` and then `GET / HTTP/1.0` I get some html code from nginx, so it's running for sure. But when I want to connect remotly, doing `telnet open 192.168.3.130 80` I get:

```
Trying 192.168.3.130...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

So I assume that there is something wrong with my network settings, maybe iptables or something else?

Next step, I turned off iptables: `service iptables stop` and it helped, now I can connect remotely using telnet.

So I think, I need to fix my iptables rules. I did some googling and found this rule `-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` but it still didn't allow me to connect remotely when iptables is up.

Can someone please help me setting a proper iptables configuration?

Comment: Look into nginx config and check if local connections are allowed.

Comment: In `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` there is nothing about local connections.

Comment: I thing that nginx just ignore telnet connections. If nginx returns html code, it should work just fine.

Comment: The problem is, that nginx returns html after connecting from telnet localy, when I do it remotely it says `no route to host`, but when I turn off iptables on server, telnet works also remotely. 
No offence, but I think you didn't read my post ;)

Comment: I read it, I just understand the problem different, sorry. Can you ping the server? You didn't write that.

Comment: Yes, I can ping it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Open the firewall dialog (Applications -> Other -> Firewall) , select "Persistent Configuration" and then proceeded to mark the "http" service as trusted on all zones.

Comment: I have only console access to the server, there are no graphic env. installed at all. 
So I've installed `system-config-firewall-tui` and walked through steps, enabling http access, but... no success :/

Comment: Ok, this works! 
The problem was, that I had also a global proxy on my machine routing everything out of the local network. Adding http rule and disabling proxy resolved the problem. Thanks @tikend!