# nginx only accessible from localhost

Tags: fedora, firewall, nginx

I setup a simple nginx server and it works if I just type `localhost` into the browser. If I try to access it from my phone in the same network, by typing the IP address of my computer, I get a "webpage not available" message. This is my nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.fedora.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/614088/nginx-works-on-my-linux-machine-but-is-not-accessible-from-other-computers-in-my) post, I [configured my firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3XfG.jpg) to allow http in the Home zone, and set the wireless network to be in that zone.

The first two entries in the INPUT chain of iptables are

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate     RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

so I don't think that's the problem.

And yet, looking at the tcpdump capture of the request from my phone I see a reply `host unreachable - admin prohibited`:

```
21:13:38.514782 IP 192.168.1.3.54982 > sidney.http: Flags [S], seq 2569820651, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3018406 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
21:13:38.514934 IP sidney > 192.168.1.3: ICMP host sidney unreachable - admin prohibited, length 68
```

Output of `firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=home`:

```
home (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wlo1
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client http mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 80/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

What could be the problem? I'm on Fedora 24.

Comment: That is the behavior I would expect for using localhost as your domain. See someone with a similar issue over at Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/804228/conflict-with-chrome-and-rfc2606 You should be able to enter the IP address and have your site served.

Comment: I do use the IP when accessing from my phone. And since the packets show up in tcpdump, it's the correct IP.

Comment: Are you able to access it locally by using the IP? I'm not sure which side that capture is from. Some home routers do have a setting to prevent your WLAN network to connect to host on the LAN and vice versa.

Comment: Yes I can access it with the IP locally. The capture is done at the computer that hosts the server. Running sshd as a ssh server works fine and can be accessed from the phone so I don't think there's anything the router is doing.

Comment: Please post the output of `firewall-cmd --list-all`.

Comment: Somehow it's working now. Maybe I just needed to restart the computer. Maybe new updates caused this? Anyway, how do I close the question?